# Date from mysql database is not displaying in html table using the date_format() function

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this piece of HTML code:

```
if($_GET["disp"]){
    include 'config.php';
    $searchstr=$_GET['cname'];
    $sql="select cname, date_format(podate, '%d-%m-%Y'), started, reason, date_format(tentdate, '%d-%m-%Y'), progress, status from info where cname='$searchstr';";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($searchstr==""){
    $message="Please enter a customer name";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message'); 
    window.location.href='retreive.php';</script>";
}
else{

    echo "<table id='info' border='1px solid black'><tr padding='2'><th>Customer Name</th><th>Purchase Order Date</th><th>Started?</th><th>Reason (If any)</th><th>Tentative start date</th><th>Progress</th><th>Current Status</th><th>New status</th></tr>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $cname=$row['cname'];
        $podate=$row['podate'];
        $started=$row['started'];
        $reason=$row['reason'];
        $tentdate=$row['tentdate'];
        $progress=$row['progress'];
        $status=$row['status'];
        echo "<tr><td>".$cname."</td><td>".$podate."</td><td>".$started."</td><td>".$reason."</td><td>".$tentdate."</td><td>".$progress."</td><td>".$status."</td><td><select id='status' name='status'>
    <option value='L1 Ongoing'>L1 Ongoing</option>
    <option value='L1 Complete'>L1 Complete</option>
    <option value='L2 Ongoing'>L2 Ongoing</option>
    <option value='L2 Complete'>L2 Complete</option>
    <option value='Invoice'>Invoice</option>
</select></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table><br>";

}
}
```

This code retrieves data from the database and displays it in an HTML table. Everything displays except the date. When I run the query in the MySQL command line though, it works fine and displays the date in the required format as well. The only place is doesn't display is in the HTML table. I need to know what I'm doing wrong. Here is the table output in the HTML table and the SQL table respectively:

[html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp0wl.png)
[sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8qb1.png)

Thank you.

Comment: `date_format(podate, '%d-%m-%Y') AS podate` ?

Comment: it worked! thanks! why though? because for the html table it must just take the value from the database and display, right?

Comment: FYI, if you had error reporting turned on/up, you'd be seeing an error displayed indicating that `$row['podate']` was attempting to use an undefined index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `date_format` function on that column.

The result key will be called something like `date_format(podate, '%d-%m-%Y')` but you are checking for `podate` in your code.

Give it an alias `podate` and everything is fine.

E.g.

`... date_format(podate, '%d-%m-%Y') AS podate ....`

Comment: ah, i get it. Thank you!